# How to draw multiple Rectangle inside SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using react with typescript. In my project, I am trying to draw multiple rectangles on my SVG. The first rectangle is easily drawn but when I am trying to draw another rectangle the previous one will disappear and then the new one is drawn. How do I maintain the previously drawn rectangle in a state and then render them?

complete sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-wood-pg5iu?file=/src/App.tsx)
here is my code:

```
const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);
    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const { xCord, yCord } = useMousePosition({ divRef });
    const [mousedown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);
    const [last_mousex, set_last_mousex] = useState(0);
    const [last_mousey, set_last_mousey] = useState(0);
    const [mousex, set_mousex] = useState(0);
    const [mousey, set_mousey] = useState(0);
    const [rectx, setrectx] = useState(0);
    const [recty, setrecty] = useState(0);
    const [rectwidth, setrectwidth] = useState(0);
    const [rectheight, setrectheight] = useState(0);

    const mouseDown = () => {
        set_last_mousex(xCord);
        set_last_mousey(yCord);
        setMouseDown(true);
      };
    
      const mouseUp = () => {
        setMouseDown(false);
      };
    
      const mouseMove = () => {
        set_mousex(xCord);
        set_mousey(yCord);
      };
    
      const addRectangle = () => {
        if (mousedown) {
          const width = Math.abs(mousex - last_mousex);
          const height = Math.abs(mousey - last_mousey);
    
          const rx = mousex < last_mousex ? mousex : last_mousex;
          const ry = mousey < last_mousey ? mousey : last_mousey;
          rectx!==rx && setrectx(rx);
          recty!==ry && setrecty(ry);
          rectheight!==height && setrectheight(height);
          rectwidth!==width && setrectwidth(width);
    
          return (
            <rect
              x={rx}
              y={ry}
              height={height}
              width={width}
            />
          );
        }
      };

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={divRef}>
       <svg
        id="svg"
        ref={svgRef}
        onMouseDown={mouseDown}
        onMouseUp={mouseUp}
        onMouseMove={mouseMove}
      >
        {addRectangle() ? (
          addRectangle()
        ) : (
          <rect
            x={rectx}
            y={recty}
            height={rectheight}
            width={rectwidth}
          />
        )}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like this

1. Save the rectangles to another state array

```
const [rectArray, setRectArray] = useState<Array<JSX.Element>>([]);
```

```
  const addRectangle = () => {
    if (mousedown) {
      const width = Math.abs(mousex - last_mousex);
      const height = Math.abs(mousey - last_mousey);

      const rx = mousex < last_mousex ? mousex : last_mousex;
      const ry = mousey < last_mousey ? mousey : last_mousey;
      rectx !== rx && setrectx(rx);
      recty !== ry && setrecty(ry);
      rectheight !== height && setrectheight(height);
      rectwidth !== width && setrectwidth(width);

      setRectArray((prevArr) => [
        ...prevArr,
        <rect x={rx} y={ry} height={height} width={width} />
      ]);
    }
  };
```

2. You should call `addRectangle`at the last line of `mouseUp`

```
  const mouseUp = () => {
    setMouseDown(false);
    addRectangle();
  };
```

3. Then you can iterate over them to show all the rectangles

```
  return (
    <div className="App" ref={divRef}>
      <svg
        id="svg"
        ref={svgRef}
        onMouseDown={mouseDown}
        onMouseUp={mouseUp}
        onMouseMove={mouseMove}
      >
        {rectArray.map((rect) => rect)}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Edit naughty-driscoll-0ytqf]

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple problems with your code:

1. you're calling the event `mouseDown` and setting the state but you're using `addRectangle` for your condition instead of just calling it as a function. This will most of the time introduce race condition issues.
2. you then return `addRectangle()` instead of adding it on an array, this is the reason why the previous rectangle is replaced.

What I suggest is:

```
const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);
    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const { xCord, yCord } = useMousePosition({ divRef });
    const [last_mousey, set_last_mousey] = useState(0);
    const [mousex, set_mousex] = useState(0);
    const [mousey, set_mousey] = useState(0);
    const [rectx, setrectx] = useState(0);
    const [recty, setrecty] = useState(0);
    const [rectwidth, setrectwidth] = useState(0);
    const [rectheight, setrectheight] = useState(0);


   const [rects, setRects] = useState([]);

    const mouseDown = () => {
        setRects(rects.concat(addRectangle(xCord, yCord)));
      };
    
      const mouseMove = () => {
        set_mousex(xCord);
        set_mousey(yCord);
      };
    
      const addRectangle = (last_mousex, last_mousey) => {
          const width = Math.abs(mousex - last_mousex);
          const height = Math.abs(mousey - last_mousey);
    
          const rx = mousex < last_mousex ? mousex : last_mousex;
          const ry = mousey < last_mousey ? mousey : last_mousey;
          rectx!==rx && setrectx(rx);
          recty!==ry && setrecty(ry);
          rectheight!==height && setrectheight(height);
          rectwidth!==width && setrectwidth(width);
    
          return (
            <rect
              x={rx}
              y={ry}
              height={height}
              width={width}
            />
          );
      };

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={divRef}>
       <svg
        id="svg"
        ref={svgRef}
        onMouseDown={mouseDown}
        onMouseMove={mouseMove}
      >
        {rects.length > 0 ? (
          rects.map(rect => rect)
        ) : (
          <rect
            x={rectx}
            y={recty}
            height={rectheight}
            width={rectwidth}
          />
        )}
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
```

- I removed `last_mousex`, `mousedown`, and `last_mousey` states and pass them directly.
- I changed the `mouseDown` function and removed the `mouseUp` they should do the same.
- Added `rects` so they its an array.
- NOTE: I did not add typescript changes on this one, just add it on your own so you can customize it.